# Conditional statement within readline() method

Tags: java

So, basically I am initially fileinputstreaming a .xml file(name ini--which basically contains a list of .txt files). However, I want to get only .txt files that are in that .xml file. How would I go about doing that? I would greatly appreciate your feedback. Thanks.

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("ini.xml"));

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // reading all lines till no more lines
    //HOWEVER ....want to place an if or any line contains method to specify to get only .txt files.
```

Your feedback would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Give us an example of the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each line contains a file name then simply test to see if the String ends with .xml

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.toLowerCase().endsWith (".xml")) continue

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a parser (SAX would be better) to extract the .txt files from the XML. Here you can find more information about parsing XML files in Java with a SAX parser: [Parsing an XML File Using SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

Comment: Quick question though, where can I get a reference of the line.(...)methods.

Comment: I was hoping something analogous to the maps method(one of them) where you can specify specific conditions such as ....if(map.containskey()) or if(map.containsValue()). However in this case line.endsWith(".xml")) continue